# Clarification about aop configuration in spring-context.xml

Tags: java, xml, spring

I am learning aop spring and came across two ways of defining aop in spring-context.xml please see below:

```
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />

    <bean id="customerBo" class="com.example.customer.impl.CustomerImpl" />

    <!-- Aspect -->
    <bean id="logAspect" class="com.example.aspect.LoggingAspect" />
```

The second one is:

```
<beans>

 <aop:aspectj-autoproxy>
<aop:include name = "logAspect"/>
<aop:aspectj-autoproxy/>

<bean id="logAspect" class="com.example.aspect.LoggingAspect" />

</beans>
```

The second one is more verbose but are they doing the same thing?

Thanks in advance for the help.

Comment: Yes. By default all aspects are including when using `<aop:aspectj-autoproxy />`, with the include you can specify which ones to include. This one can be nice when using certain aspects during development but not during production. You could specify a profile which includes the correct ones for either development or production.

Comment: Ok thanks a lot for th response, make sense now